# gcc - grab symbol from particular library

Tags: gcc, ld

I have two libraries with several overlapping symbol definitions.   Symbols in library A should take precedence, but library A happens to override an important symbol I need from library B.  Because I need symbols from both, simply reordering the libraries on the command line is not an option.   I'm wondering if there's any mechanism in gcc to say 'get symbol foo from library B'  (note: I could rename the symbol in library B, but I'd prefer to not have to modify the library itself).

I'm not finding anything online, but I thought I'd ask in case I'm missing something.

Comment: Have you considered using `dlopen()` et al.?

Comment: Which library a symbol will be taken from depends on whether the libraries are static or shared, where the symbol is referenced, and which other symbols live in the same object file. So this could become very hairy very quickly.